# Add new interface on Centos7 without NetworkManager

Tags: centos, wifi, network-interface

I have a wifi dongle on an RPI. When I plug it in I see the following in messages:

```
[50863.497490] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[51167.660462] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[51167.791546] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b812
[51167.791769] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[51167.791976] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter
[51167.792140] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[51167.792267] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 123456
```

I cannot/will NOT use NetworkManager due to numerous issues it causes with routing tables/other nics/bad experiences in the past. Please do not suggest its use.

I don't know what the next steps are to add this interface as a NIC on the machine.

EDIT: I think I have found the drivers - but when I try to use DKMS to build with the driver, I get

```
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=4.14.127-v7.1.el7 KVER=4.14.127-v7.1.el7....(bad exit status: 2)
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.14.127-v7.1.el7 (armv7hl)
```

Relevant log results:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl88x2bu-5.2.4.4 for kernel 4.14.127-v7.1.el7 (armv7hl)
Sat Jul 27 19:22:29 UTC 2019
/bin/sh: bc: command not found
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.127-v7.1.el7/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.14.127-v7.1.el7'
Makefile:646: arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `arch/armv7l/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/4.14.127-v7.1.el7'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Assuming the `dmesg` is complete and there are no lines after that, next step is finding the correct driver, because no driver gets loaded. That will be tough for 802.11ac adapters. And Realtek in particular. Googling for `0bda:b812` might turn up something.

Comment: I found some links referring to the rtl8822bu driver, but all the forums reference Ubuntu. Can I try installing rtl8822bu somehow on Centos?